# Error groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException while updating form created by scaffolding true

Tags: grails, groovy, scaffolding

As I created a scaffold crud with grails by adding `static scaffold = Product` in my controller which is exist on seperate package, everything is working fine as expected, but while saving the data Its giving me groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException error from the edit page.

Please find the following stacktrace for the errr info.

unfortunately I didn't get any helpful article or answer to resolve this issue.

Please find the following stacktrace for the errr info.

**Error**

```
2019-06-18 16:43:55.494 ERROR --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : ReadOnlyPropertyException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /product/update/1 - parameters:
Cannot set readonly property: properties for class: com.sun.Product. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:62)
    at grails.plugin.cookiesession.CookieSessionFilter.doFilterInternal(CookieSessionFilter.groovy:86)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: properties for class: com.sun.Product
    at grails.rest.RestfulController.$tt__update(RestfulController.groovy:150)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

**Product (Domain Class)**

```
class Product {
    static auditable = [ignoreEvents:["onSave"]]
    Integer id
    String slug
    boolean active = true
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    String name
    String description
    CoverageType type
    ProductType productType
    boolean isOffline = false

    static transients = []

    static belongsTo = [provider:Provider]
    static hasMany = [productAddonList: ProductAddon]

    static constraints = {
        productType display: false
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return slug
    }
}
```

I just want to save data successfully either its edit page or create page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html `static constraints = {
        productType display: false
    }` I don't think display is a correct constraints. `static transients = []` should not be needed,  had to say otherwise without being behind it - try adding try catch and review throwable or Error to see what is going wrong

Comment: You said "Please find the following stacktrace for the errr info." and then didn't include a stacktrace.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sorry, I have updated the error info

Comment: Is the source code for `Product.groovy` defined somewhere under `grails-app/domain/...`?